# How to use count() WHERE IN in laravel DB:raw

Tags: mysql, laravel

How to use count() WHERE IN in `Laravel` DB:raw

```
$report=`societyReport`::select('society_reports.id','society_reports.body','society_reports.created_at',DB::raw("count(votes.vote) as count WHERE vote = 1"))
        ->`leftjoin`('votes', 'votes.society_reports_id','=','society_reports.id')
        ->`groupBy`('society_reports.id')
        ->`orderBy`('society_reports.id', 'DESC')
        ->paginate(10);
```

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Where vote = 1

Answer (score 2):

See this for corrections in your structure :

```
$report= SocietyReport::leftjoin('votes', 'votes.society_reports_id','=','society_reports.id')
        ->groupBy('society_reports.id')
        ->orderBy('society_reports.id', 'DESC')
        ->select(
          'society_reports.id',
          'society_reports.body',
          'society_reports.created_at',
          \DB::raw("count(votes.vote) as count")
        )
        ->where('vote', 1)
        ->paginate(10);
```

The problem is `select()` is used to select columns or the aggregate values. If you want to add where clause, you need to do `->where()`